# luatex has problem reading "/text"

Tags: luatex

Please help my thesis is on due. luatex has problem reading "/text". For exampple: {$\text{Spannung }\sigma\text{ in MPa}$},

```
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-5,
xmax=275,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={$\text{Dehnung }\epsilon\text{ in \%}$},
ymin=0,
ymax=4,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={$\text{Spannung }\sigma\text{ in MPa}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Spannungs-Dehnungs-Diagramm - Sylgard 15:1 - 0\%-Pulver-Massenanteil},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.5)}, anchor=west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]'
```

Comment: Why not `Spannung  $\sigma$ in MPa`?

Comment: Thank you!. Also it has problems reading "%\addlegendentry{Probe C}" you know why?

Comment: Please, complete the code to a minimal document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so that we can test it. And welcome!

Comment: `\text` isn't defined in latex it's normally defined by amsmath package but since you have not shown your code or your error it is hard to say much to help.